# asp.net core increase session duration. IdleTimeout not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I want a session to last a few days, even if the browser window closes, so I used this settings in Startup.cs :

```
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(720);
        });
```

However, it seems to have no effect. The session keeps resetting after a while even if the browser tab with the website stays open.  How can i fix this ?

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue with setting the IdleTimeout to 720 minutes (12 hours). My session keeps expiring after around 5 1/2 hours. I'm running on it on IIS and made sure the idle timeout in iis was set 12 hours too and that it wasn't recycling the app pool at the wrong times. Still not working.

Comment: Session cookie is set to expire When the browsing session ends for some reason .

Comment: Can that happen while the browser tab is still open? I don't mind the session expiring when I close the browser but right now it's expiring even when I have the site open.

Comment: It happens when browser is open sometimes for me.

Comment: Does the site restart during this time period? If so you may not have persisted your DataProtection keys, so you can't read the old session cookie after restarting.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because session cookie expires in [`session`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age). [`IdleTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state) setting how long server should store session and it's "invisible" to browser

In more details: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session` using `CookieBuilder` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` which sets `default(DateTimeOffset?)` in `Expires` in `CookieOptions` cuz `Expiration.HasValue` return `false`

If you will override remember about `public override TimeSpan? Expiration` in `SessionCookieBuilder`

Comment: @J.Doe , I faced the same issue , can you refer any post how to solve this ?